# how to run chrome driver in headless mode using python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, headless

i executing my program in headless mood.

**I am did this**

```
opt = Options()
opt.headless = True
opt.add_argument("--start-maximized")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
browser.get("https://www.instagram.com")
time.sleep(5)
browser.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.jpg")
print("yes")
username_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']").send_keys("hidden")
```

**getting error**

[it is screenshot taken after entering link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q7H2.png)

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"input[name='username']"}

**and**

when i am run in normal mood its working properly
there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should maximize the screen in headless mode and this will resolve your problem.

```
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the useragent you're using is being blocked.
You can try:

```
opt.add_argument('user-agent={Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36}')
```

With that option, I found this selector.